# How do I locate the MAC address of my computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, mac-address

I am unable to locate the [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) in a new computer with Windows 7.  I've tried `ipconfig /all` in the console to which I got `no items match your search`.  I also tried `getmac`.  A screen flashed very briefly with what appeared to be the information, but it was not there long enough to read.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You have probably typed that into the Start Menu search dialog, which does execute the command but doesn't show it as the command prompt window disappears as soon as the command has been executed. This is the normal bahavior of command prompt applications, they close as soon as it is done.

In order for the command prompt to stay, you have to run those commands through the command prompt. The command prompt doesn't disappear after execution of a program; so, you can see the output as a result.

1. Click the Start Button or press the Windows key.
2. In the start menu search, type `cmd`.
3. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the command prompt, or click on the `cmd` entry that appears.
4. Type in `ipconfig /all` or `getmac` and it should execute both commands and the window will remain open such that you can see the output.

Note:
`getmac` is great for just mac addresses `ipconfig` is good for ip addresses and `ipconfig /all` is great for IP address and a lot of other useless info (like unused connections)

to use `getmac`

1. type `cmd` in the search box and press <kbd>enter</kbd> or run window (<kbd>windows logo</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>)
2. then type `getmac` (no ipconfig necessary, in fact that wont work) and let it run (it may take a few seconds to rertrieve the info)

if you use `ipconfig` and `ipconfig` dose not have enough info use `ipconfig /all`

Answer (score 42):

A simple way to get the MAC address(es) of your network adapter(s):

On a command prompt type

```
getmac
```

Example:

[image: getmac mac address of network adapter]

Comment: +1. I was not aware about this one. I always use ipconfig /all, but this is a lot easier.

Comment: I think that the ethernet address will typically be first, and the wifi address will typically be second.

Comment: Also, if you use `getmac /v` then it will show the name of the adapter and the connection state.  Much easier if you have multiple network adapters, especially if you have some virtual ones from virtual machine software.

Comment: Does it work for interfaces that aren't connected? For some reason (or unreason ;-p), `ipconfig` never shows me the MACs of interfaces that are not connected. This may be the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 28):

For Windows Vista and Windows 7, in the control panel:

Open the **Network and Sharing Center > Local Area Connection > Details > Physical Address**.

[image: Network and Sharing Center MAC address]

Comment: Annoyingly only accessible when connected, as is the MAC from `ipconfig` – a pain when I need the MAC of windows machines before they connect.

Answer (score 8):

You can also locate the MAC address using VBScript:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select MACAddress from Win32_NetworkAdapter where DeviceID=1")
For Each objItem in colItems
    Wscript.Echo "MAC Address: " & objItem.MACAddress 
Next
```

Comment: *getmac* does the same thing and is built into Windows.

Comment: that's not called reinventing the wheel. That's called "there are many ways to do things". vbscript works almost in every version of windows , including Win9x. getmac is not available in every version.

Comment: Well, it's a Window 7 question, so why bother writing a whoooole script when you can just type a command?

Comment: @TFM: Because the script can give you the MAC address only, while `getmac` requires output parsing...

Comment: @TFM: That *and* WMI can be used over the network natively, without having to "reinvent the wheel" with SSH/psexec/WS-Remoting. Just change `strComputer`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Get-NetAdapter` PowerShell cmdlet.

It displays a nice table that identify each network interface with its MAC address.

[image]

Comment: Only for Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1.

Comment: What is the minimum required version of PowerShell?

Comment: AFAIK the cmdlet was introduced in Windows 8.1. Upgrading PowerShell won't install it on older systems.