# How do I find out the MAC address of my Wi-Fi card in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, mac-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to locate MAC address in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/66988/how-to-locate-mac-address-in-windows-7)

How do I find out the MAC address of my Wi-Fi card in Windows 7?
Is there some screen in the GUI I can look at? Or something in a DOS window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, type "ipconfig /all" on the command line.