# Trying to find MAC addresses across a network

Tags: windows, mac-address

When using `nbtstat -a (IP address)`, will it return the true MAC hardware address of the machine?

Comment: Could you add the OS (or multiple of them)? I guess everyone is assuming windows since you mentioned `nbtstat`, but that is still an assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

**1**
Collect them from a directly connected computer, or

**2**
Or run a program on the local computer you are trying to get the mac from, e.g. `getmac` which will return output like this:

[image]

Or via vb:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select MACAddress from Win32_NetworkAdapter where DeviceID=1")
For Each objItem in colItems
    Wscript.Echo "MAC Address: " & objItem.MACAddress 
Next
```

Source of the script: [this very similar question on S.U.](http://superuser.com/questions/66988/how-do-i-locate-the-mac-address-of-my-computer)

**3**
Or get them from the switches the computer is connected to. Precisely how depends on the brand of the managed switch.

**4**
Or write them down whenever you get new hardware and store them in a inventory database. (Mostly useful for large corporation, which will store much more information such as model, type, CPUs, RAM, helldesk calls, ...)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `nbtstat -a` you need to specify a HOSTNAME.

To use an IP address, it's `nbtstat -A <ip>`.

Other options from Unix are `arp -a` (which doesn't really scan everything available).

Answer (score 0):

***True MAC address***? ***True MAC address***? Unless you pull the [NIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller) and take it back to the manufacturer there is truly no way of knowing for sure when there are programs that can easily change your hardware address WITHIN SECONDS...

***Seconds***.